# How do you make spark-submit arguments come right after "spark-submit" when debugging in vs code insiders

Tags: python, apache-spark, debugging, visual-studio-code, spark-submit

I am debugging a spark job (pyspark) in vs code in a remote ssh session (vs code insiders)

Using vs code inisders 1.35.0 with remote ssh.

This is my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: IDI Spark Training",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": ["--queue", "ds-others"],
            "linux": {
                "pythonPath": "/bin/spark-submit"
            },

            "program": "${file}",
        }

    ]
}
```

For my spark cluster to execute job, I need to pass specific queue names to the spark-submit command. When I execute jobs manually, I use

```
spark-submit --queue ds-others training.py
```

That works fine when executed in my terminal

Based on the launch.json above, when I start the debugger, the Debug console executes:

```
cd /hadoop/met_scripts/datascience/dnaanalytics_us_group/us_grp_mo_idi_fwa ; env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 /bin/spark-submit /home/nokyere/.vscode-server-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.5.17517/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 40845 /hadoop/met_scripts/datascience/dnaanalytics_us_group/us_grp_mo_idi_fwa/python/training.py --queue ds-others
```

So it looks like vs code adds its own arguments right after spark-submit but the arguments I specified only gets passed after the python script has been passed. This causes my job not to run hence the debugging doesn't work. I don't get an error message. I only know the job has not kicked off because of how vs code adds the arguments needed for the job to run. When I submit the job via spark-submit and pass the arguments after passing the script name, the same behavior is observed; but when I pass the arrangements before the script name is works just fine.

I wonder why vs code passes the user specified arguments after the script name and if there's anything I can change the order in which VS Code passes the arguments. I need the "--queue ds-others" to come before the script name. Thanks.

Comment: A maintainer of Python Extension here, unfortunately this feature isn't supported. This isn't supported today. Please feel free to create an issue on our repo requesting this feature.